# why slideToggle jumping? and how to get it to apply only to article clicked?

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

Ok so here is my jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8947F/

basically the slideToggle seems to add then take away some height at the bottom so that it looks like it jumps...

Also the clicking affects all of the hidden divs, how do I get it to only apply to the one in particular

here's my jquery

```
$(function() {
$('article .folder-hover').hide();

    $('article').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('.folder-hover').show();
    },
function(){
    $(this).children('.folder-hover').hide();
});    

});

$(function() {
$('article .folder-items').hide();    


$("article").click(function () {
  $(".folder-items").slideToggle("slow");
});
});
```

any way to get it so it only affects the child div when it's parent is begin clicked?
and what is up with that 'jump'???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8947F/14/

works nice n smooth!

Answer (score 1):

Because it is selecting all the `folder-items`. You should restrict it to find with in the current article being clicked by passing a context(`this` in your case). Try this.

```
$(function() {
    $('article .folder-hover').hide();
    $('article').hover(function(){
        $(this).children('.folder-hover').show();
    },
    function(){
        $(this).children('.folder-hover').hide();
    });    
});

$(function() {
    $('article .folder-items').hide();    

    $("article").click(function () {
      $(".folder-items", this).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Remove height 100% from folder-items css class this will fix the jumping issue

```
.folder-items {
    clear: left;
    padding-top: 12px;
    margin-left: 48px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8947F/10/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
.folder-items {
    height:auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8947F/4/